# Can we use DynamoDB Mapper for atomic counters(Java)?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I was looking at DynamoDB documentation and googling, but I could not find any implementation of atomic counters using DynamoDB mapper.

Is this possible? Or only the low level API can be used for this?

Answer (score 3):

With the Java API you should look at [UpdateItemRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/UpdateItemRequest.html) with AttributeAction.ADD

The [lower level api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) can also be used

Edit after comment..

I am not aware of that option. Perhaps you should edit your question and add the code you wished was available.

If you want a @DynamoDBAutoIncrementAttribute for an integer - there isn't one.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.. I wanted to use the DynamoDB mapper... UpdateItemRequest is not a part of the mapper..

Comment: Chen is correct that there is not an option to do this today in the DynamoDBMapper.  However, it is common for developers to use both the high-level DynamoDBMapper for most things, and then also use the low-level API for other things like this.  There is a helpful method "marshallIntoObject" on the DynamoDBMapper that can be used to take a low-level Item that you get back from a getItem or updateItem call, and turn it into your class object automatically.

Comment: That's all well and good until you get to the point where the documentation tells you that the low-level API (or the Mapper for that matter) does not provide convenient constructs to replicate the transparent mechanisms the Mapper provides such as Optimistic Locking and Timestamping.